# Generating random samples from a custom distribution

Tags: r, sampling, uniform-distribution

I am trying to generate random samples from a custom pdf using R. My pdf is:
$$f_{X}(x) = \frac{3}{2} (1-x^2), 0 \le x \le 1$$

I generated uniform samples and then tried to transform it to my custom distribution. I did this by finding the cdf of my distribution ($F_{X}(x)$) and setting it to the uniform sample ($u$) and solving for $x$.

$$ F_{X}(x) = \Pr[X \le x]  = \int_{0}^{x} \frac{3}{2} (1-y^2) dy = \frac{3}{2} (x - \frac{x^3}{3}) $$

To generate a random sample with the above distribution, get a uniform sample $u \in[0,1]$ and solve for $x$ in $$\frac{3}{2} (x - \frac{x^3}{3}) = u $$

I implemented it in `R` and I don't get the expected distribution. Can anyone point out the flaw in my understanding?

```
nsamples <- 1000;
x <- runif(nsamples);

f <- function(x, u) { 
  return(3/2*(x-x^3/3) - u);
}

z <- c();
for (i in 1:nsamples) {
  # find the root within (0,1) 
  r <- uniroot(f, c(0,1), tol = 0.0001, u = x[i])$root;
  z <- c(z, r);
}
```

Comment: Must be a coding mistake.  I don't use R, so I can't say what the mistake is exactly -- but I just coded up your solution (taking care to take the middle root of the cubic polynomial, which always lies between 0 and 1), and I get good agreement between the samples and the expected distribution. Could it be a problem with your root finder?  What's wrong with the samples you're getting?

Comment: I tried your code (which is not very efficient, by the way) and do get the expected distribution.

Comment: @jpillow and @Aniko My mistake. When I used `nsamples <- 1e6` it was a good match.

Comment: @Aniko Can you suggest ways to make it efficient?

Comment: @Anand One way is to observe that $x = 2\sin(\arcsin(u)/3)$, allowing direct calculation of $x$ in terms of $u$.

Comment: @whuber How did you obtain the closed form solution? It would be helpful to understand the procedure. Thanks.

Comment: @Anand http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Trigonometric_.28and_hyperbolic.29_method

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you figured out that your code works, but @Aniko pointed out that you could improve its efficiency. Your biggest speed gain would probably come from pre-allocating memory for `z` so that you're not growing it inside a loop. Something like `z <- rep(NA, nsamples)` should do the trick. You may get a small speed gain from using `vapply()` (which specifies the returned variable type) instead of an explicit loop (there's a great [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275896/is-rs-apply-family-more-than-syntactic-sugar) on the apply family).

```
> nsamples <- 1E5
> x <- runif(nsamples)
> f <- function(x, u) 1.5 * (x - (x^3) / 3) - u
> z <- c()
> 
> # original version
> system.time({
+ for (i in 1:nsamples) {
+   # find the root within (0,1) 
+   r <- uniroot(f, c(0,1), tol = 0.0001, u = x[i])$root
+   z <- c(z, r)
+ }
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
  49.88    0.00   50.54 
> 
> # original version with pre-allocation
> z.pre <- rep(NA, nsamples)
> system.time({
+ for (i in 1:nsamples) {
+   # find the root within (0,1) 
+   z.pre[i] <- uniroot(f, c(0,1), tol = 0.0001, u = x[i])$root
+   }
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
   7.55    0.01    7.78 
> 
> 
> 
> # my version with sapply
> my.uniroot <- function(x) uniroot(f, c(0, 1), tol = 0.0001, u = x)$root
> system.time({
+   r <- vapply(x, my.uniroot, numeric(1))
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
   6.61    0.02    6.74 
> 
> # same results
> head(z)
[1] 0.7803198 0.2860108 0.5153724 0.2479611 0.3451658 0.4682738
> head(z.pre)
[1] 0.7803198 0.2860108 0.5153724 0.2479611 0.3451658 0.4682738
> head(r)
[1] 0.7803198 0.2860108 0.5153724 0.2479611 0.3451658 0.4682738
```

And you don't need the `;` at the end of each line (are you a MATLAB convert?).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer and for pointing out `vapply`. I have been coding in `C/C++` for a very long time and that is the reason for `;` affliction!

Comment: +1 It looks like replacing `uniroot` by a direct solution speeds things up by three more orders of magnitude: you should have no trouble obtaining around $10^7$ variates per second.