# Problems generating a sample from a custom distribution with log

Tags: r, sampling, density-function, sample

I'm trying to generate a sample from a family of distributions. In particular I would like to be able to obtain a sample from the survival function:

$$1-F(x) = c x^{-a}  \log^b(x)$$
with a proper domain so that F is defined and it is a survival function, from different values of $c$, $b$ and $a$.

For example:
$$1-F(x) \approx  \tfrac{\log(x)}{x^2}, x>\sqrt{e}$$

Roughly speaking I need a function $F$ such that the distribution is heavy tailed and behaves like $1-F(x) = c x^{-a}  \log^b(x)$, as $x$ goes to $+ \infty$.

I've tried many ways, because I found several examples:

- 1 [Generating random samples from a custom distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12843/generating-random-samples-from-a-custom-distribution)
- 2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134786/simulate-data-from-non-standard-density-function
- 3 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23570952/simulate-from-an-arbitrary-continuous-probability-distribution
- 4 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508400/generating-random-sample-from-the-quantiles-of-unknown-density-in-r
- 5 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594121/how-do-i-best-simulate-an-arbitrary-univariate-random-variate-using-its-probabil

But anytime, even for the simplest function with $b=1$ and $a=2$ errors come out. I think it's because maybe, due to the log, some algorithms work with all real numbers and cannot be confined to positive numbers.

Which is the easiest way for a pdf/cdf with a log in it? Is it difficult due to the fact that it's hard to invert the function `xlogx`?

If I have to use some of the previous methods I can show you my achivements and where I got stuck!

EDIT 1
Thanks to `whuber` I succeded in building the code, here you are:

```
# Simulating data from G(x) = 1-F(x) = c * x^(-a) * (log(x))^b
# Case: b > 0
pxlog <- function(x, a=5, b=2, c=(a*exp(1)/b)^b) {((1-c*x^(-a)*(log(x))^b))}                 # G
dxlog <- function(x, a=5, b=2, c=(a*exp(1)/b)^b) {c*(x^(-1-a))*((log(x))^(-1+b))*(-b+a*log(x))}
qxlog <- function(y, a=5, b=2, c=(a*exp(1)/b)^b) {exp(-(b/a)*lambert_Wm1(-(a/b)*((1-y)/c)^(1/b)))}   # inversa di G

# Domain for the functions: x > exp(b/a)

# Generating Samples
rxlog <- function(n, a=5, b=2, c=(a*exp(1)/b)^b) qxlog(runif(n),a,b,c)

# Testing Samples
hist(rxlog(10000, 2, 10), breaks=50, freq = F, col="grey", label=F)
curve(dxlog(x, 2, 10), exp(10/2), add= TRUE, col="red")
```

The result is that it works... almost! If I use values of $b$ greater than $a$, or in general, if $b-a>-1$, fitting density/histogram creates problem.

For example $a=2, b=10$
[image]

or with $a=3, b=4$ (adjusting the breaks in hist)

[image]

Which is the problem? And second question, how can I include, if it's possible, the domain information about $F$ in the definition of $F$ itself?
Thanks!

EDIT 2 For $b>0$ the distribution I'm looking for can be assumed as the log gamma distribution. You can find it in the [Actuar](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/actuar/index.html) library in R. Testing "my" distribution (the one with the code in EDIT 1) with that one there are some differences... but I think that it's just because I've made some mistakes!

Comment: $f$ is not a proper density function for $a=b=1$: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%28log%28x%29%2Fx%2Cx%3D1..infinity%29%3B

Comment: Yes, sorry, for $a>1.5$ is fine. (I've tested for $a=2$)

Comment: This makes no sense for $b\ne 0$, because $1-F(1) = 1^{-a}\log^b(1) = 0$ (for $b\gt 0$; it's undefined for $b\lt 0$) shows $F(1)=1$, whence (since $F$ must increase to $1$ as $x\to\infty$), $F(x)=1$ for all $x\in [1,\infty)$. That is the distribution function for an atom at $1$.

Comment: It's not hard to invert $x\log(x)$: use the Lambert W function.

Comment: Thanks. Does Lambert W function work with logaritm powers too?
Anyway, I want to try with the Rejection sampling. Let's see what happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**We can generate random variates from this distribution by inverting it.**

This means solving $1 - F(x) = q$ (which lies between $0$ and $1$, implying $a\gt 0$) for $x$.  Notice that $\log^b(x)$ will be undefined or negative (which won't work) unless $x \gt 1$.  Leave aside the case $b=0$ for the moment. The solutions are slightly different depending on the sign of $b$.  When $b \lt 0$, $$x=\exp(y)$$ and solve for $y \gt 0$:

$$q^{1/b} = (c \log^b(x) x^{-a})^{1/b} = c^{1/b} y\exp(-\frac{a}{b} y),$$

whence

$$-\frac{b}{a} W\left(-\frac{a}{b} \left(\frac{q}{c}\right)^{1/b}\right)= y.$$

$W$ is the primary branch of the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function): when $w = u \exp(u)$ for $u \ge -1$, $W(w)=u$.  The solid lines in the figure show this branch.

[image: ![Figure: Plots of the inverse of W and W itself]

When $b\gt 0$, let $$x = \exp(-y)$$ and solve as before, yielding

$$\frac{b}{a} W\left(-\frac{a}{b} \left(\frac{q}{c}\right)^{1/b}\right)= y.$$

Because we are interested in the behavior as $x\to \infty$, which corresponds to $y\to -\infty$, the relevant branch is the one shown with the dashed lines in the figure.  Notice that the argument of $W$ must lie in the interval $[-1/e, 0]$.  This will happen only when $c$ is sufficiently large.  Since $0 \le q \le 1$, this implies

$$c \ge  \left(\frac{e a}{b}\right)^b.$$

Values along either branch of $W$ are readily computed using Newton-Raphson.  Depending on the values of $a,b,$ and $c$ chosen, between one and a dozen iterations will be needed.

Finally, when $b=0$ the logarithmic term is $1$ and we can readily solve

$$x = \left(\frac{c}{q}\right)^{1/a} = \exp\left(-\frac{1}{a}\log\left(\frac{q}{c}\right)\right).$$

(In some sense the limiting value of $(q/c)^{1/b}/b$ gives the natural logarithm, as we would hope.)

In either case, **to generate variates from this distribution, stipulate $a$, $b$, and $c$, then generate uniform variates in the range $[0,1]$ and substitute their values for $q$ in the appropriate formula.**

---

Here are examples with $a=5$ and $b=\pm 2$ to illustrate.  $10,000$ independent variates were drawn and summarized with histograms of $y$ and $x$.  For negative $b$ (top), I chose a value of $c$ that gives a picture that is not terribly skewed. For positive $b$ (bottom), the most extreme possible value of $c$ was chosen.  Shown for comparison are solid curves graphing the derivative of the distribution function $F$.  The match is excellent in both cases.

**Negative $b$**

[image: Figure: Negative b]

**Positive $b$**

[image: Figure: Positive b]

---

Here is working code to compute $W$ in `R`, with an example showing its use.  It is vectorized to perform Newton-Raphson steps in parallel for a large number of values of the argument, which is ideal for efficient generation of random variates.

(*Mathematica*, which generated the figures here, implements $W$ as `ProductLog`.  The negative branch used here is the one with index $-1$ in *Mathematica*'s numbering.  It returns the same values in the examples given here, which are computed to at least 12 significant figures.)

```R
W <- function(q, tol.x2=1e-24, tol.W2=1e-24, iter.max=15, verbose=FALSE) {
  #
  # Define the function and its derivative.
  #
  W.inverse <- function(z) z * exp(z)
  W.inverse.prime <- function(z) exp(z) + W.inverse(z)
  #
  # Functions to take one Newton-Raphson step.
  #
  NR <- function(x, f, f.prime) x - f(x) / f.prime(x)
  step <- function(x, q) NR(x, function(y) W.inverse(y) - q, W.inverse.prime)
  #
  # Pick a good starting value.  Use the principal branch for positive
  # arguments and its continuation (to large negative values) for 
  # negative arguments.
  #
  x.0 <- ifelse(q < 0, log(-q), log(q + 1))
  #
  # True zeros must be handled specially.
  #
  i.zero <- q == 0
  q.names <- q
  q[i.zero] <- NA
  #
  # Newton-Raphson iteration.
  #
  w.1 <- W.inverse(x.0)
  i <- 0
  if (verbose) x <- x.0
  if (any(!i.zero, na.rm=TRUE)) {
    while (i < iter.max) {
      i <- i + 1
      x.1 <- step(x.0, q)
      if (verbose) x <- rbind(x, x.1)
      if (mean((x.0/x.1 - 1)^2, na.rm=TRUE) <= tol.x2) break
      w.1 <- W.inverse(x.1)
      if (mean(((w.1 - q)/(w.1 + q))^2, na.rm=TRUE) <= tol.W2) break
      x.0 <- x.1
    }
  }
  x.0[i.zero] <- 0
  w.1[i.zero] <- 0
  rv <- list(W=x.0,                              # Values of Lambert W
             W.inverse=w.1,                      # W * exp(W)
             Iterations=i,
             Code=ifelse(i < iter.max, 0, -1),   # 0 for success
             Tolerances=c(x2=tol.x2, W2=tol.W2))
  names(rv$W) <- q.names                         # $
  if (verbose) {
    rownames(x) <- 1:nrow(x) - 1
    rv$Steps <- x                                # $
  }
  return (rv)
}
#
# Test on both positive and negative arguments
#
q <- rbind(Positive = 10^seq(-3, 3, length.out=7), 
           Negative = -exp(seq(-(1+1e-15), -600, length.out=7)))
for (i in 1:nrow(q)) {
  rv <- W(q[i, ], verbose=TRUE)
  cat(rv$Iterations, " steps:", rv$W, "\n")
  #print(rv$Steps, digits=13)                     # Shows the steps
  #print(rbind(q[i, ], rv$W.inverse), digits=12)  # Checks correctness
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved my life :)
I've tried and it works, I put the code in the first post. But I have a question because when I try with $a<b$ the density function and the histogram do not mach. And the more is $b-a$ the more it doesn't fit. Is it a numerical problem, I mean, wrong approximation or something like that, or is there an error? Thank you very much.

Comment: I am not having problems with $a\lt b$ generally. For example, I was able to produce similar graphics for $a=1/10,b=20$. Notice that as $a$ shrinks towards $0$ and/or $b$ increases, the distribution's right tail becomes very long. The values of $y$ are fine, but once they get below $-700$ or so, computing $\exp(-y)$ will overflow double-precision numbers. You also might want to verify that you're computing $W$ correctly.  I'll post code for that.

Comment: So, you are telling me that, for greater values of b, I cannot rely on the x-plot but I just have to use the y one? Thanks.

Comment: As you can see, the distribution can be incredibly skewed, specially for smaller $a$. A histogram of $y$ will typically show more detail than a histogram of $x$.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I've noticed that the distribution I was looking for $b>0$ is the loggamma distribution.